# PHP Can't get variable from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

So I am having trouble getting int column from my database. I have this code:

```
<?php
    $raffleid = 1;

    $checkSlots = "SELECT slots FROM raffle WHERE raffleid = '$raffleid'";
    $btns = $pdo->query($checkSlots);
    echo (string)$btns;

?>
```

I get this error:

> "Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string"

I just can't seem to get it to echo. I have tried binding it to a string and just trying to echo $btns. Here is a pic of my database.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlO3S.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO creates an object from which you have to get your data. The object consists out of rows with in the rows columns as an array:

```
$row=$btns->fetch(); // Gets a row
echo $row["slots"];
```

should work.

Comment: Can I use that anywhere else in my php file? Like if I want to call it?

Comment: Every time you call fetch, it tries to get a new row from the result of the query, so usually you would build a loop to fetch the data and use it at once.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) *$btns = $pdo->query($checkSlots);* returns an **object**:

> PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a
>   PDOStatement object

So you cannot just echo what it returns, instead you need to execute any of the methods offered by the object, eg: *fetch()* method.